# Calculating using calculated columns in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data is grouped by id and by checkdate, such that each person has a row for each checkDate they received a check. I have columns with a gross amount(YTDGross) and a deferral amount(YTD401K) for each checkDate.

I want to calculate 3 additional columns.

The first calculates a match amount (Match) using the following formula:

```
IIF(YTD401K<=.04*YTDGross,IIF(YTDGross<=265000,YTD401K-PriorYTD401kMatch,
IIF((YTD401K-PriorYTD401kMatch)>(10600-PriorYTD401kMatch),10600-PriorYTD401kMatch,YTD401K-PriorYTD401kMatch)),
IIF(YTDGross<=265000,(ROUND(.04*YTDGross,2)-PriorYTD401kMatch),10600-PriorYTD401kMatch)) AS Match
```

The formula itself is irrelevant except that it refers to another column that also needs to be calculated: PriorYTD401kMatch. And this column in turn is calculated from a third column- it is the YTD401KMatch from the previous row.

YTD401KMatch is simply the PriorYTD401kMatch + Match

I can't see how this is possible in SQL Server 2012 as each of the three new columns is dependent on each other in a circuitous manner. Someone feel free to show me the light.

Here is the latest select before I am stuck:

```
    SELECT 
c.co,
c.id,
c.checkDate,
yg.gross,
yg.YTDGross,
c.cont401k,
SUM(c.cont401k) OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY c.checkDate) AS YTD401K,
c.match401K,
SUM(c.match401k) OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY c.checkDate) AS YTD401KMatch
INTO
#YTD401K
FROM
#Contributions c
FULL JOIN
#YTDGross yg ON
yg.co = c.co AND yg.id = c.id AND yg.checkDate = c.checkDate
```

Comment: You might have better readability if you were to use a stored procedure.

Comment: Could use nested subqueries. Or could create a view with the base calculation, then base your query on the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186243%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).  For simplicity, I've changed your names, but the basic idea is this:  first, convert your dates to consecutive ids (for each person) to make finding the next one easy.  Then start at the beginning, where the calculation should be a little different (there is no previous day).  And then add in the next day, this time with the general calculation.  Rinse and repeat.

```
WITH Ids AS
(
   SELECT 
       t.Val, 
       t.Person,
       t.Day,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER -- consecutive ids
       (
         PARTITION BY t.Person -- for each person
         ORDER BY t.Day ASC -- in order of dates
       ) AS DayId
     FROM Tbl t
)
, RecCte AS
(
  -- base case: first day for each person
  SELECT 
      i.Val, 
      i.Person, 
      i.Day, 
      i.DayId, 
      (10.0-i.Val)/2.0 AS Calc, -- initial calculation
      CAST(0 AS REAL) AS PrevCalc -- placeholder
    FROM Ids i
    WHERE i.DayId = 1 -- first day

  UNION ALL

  -- recursive case: later days
  SELECT 
      n.Val, 
      n.Person, 
      n.Day, 
      n.DayId, 
      (10.0 - n.Val - p.Calc)/2 AS Calc, -- the general calculation
      p.Calc AS PrevCalc -- copy value for reference
    FROM Ids n -- next day
    INNER JOIN RecCte p -- prev day
      ON n.Person = p.Person
        AND n.DayId = p.DayId+1 -- consecutive ids
)
  SELECT *
    FROM RecCte a
    ORDER BY a.Person ASC, a.Day ASC
;
```